# Nav Bar Button - Page "Jumps" (or creates white space above nav bar) when button clicked

Tags: html, css

Clicking a nav button causes the whole nav bar to jump down and insert white space while the next page loads. How can I remedy this?

Before clicking: http://i60.tinypic.com/zv1web.jpg

After clicking (whilst next page is loading): http://i58.tinypic.com/2cz8vsw.jpg

Here is the **HTML** for the NAV button:

```
    <a ng-class="{active: $location.path().substring(1) === page.path}" class="item ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="page in headerMenu" ng-href="/explore" href="/explore">Explore</a>
```

And the **CSS**:

```
.main-menu.ui.inverted.menu .nav-wrap .item {
  padding: 1.8em 1em;
}

.main-menu.ui.inverted.menu .nav-wrap .item {
  padding: 1.8em 1em;
}

.ui.menu .item {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.ui.menu .item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .78571em .95em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease,background .2s ease,box-shadow .2s ease;
  transition: opacity .2s ease,background .2s ease,box-shadow .2s ease;
}
```

Comment: Added HTML, but I guess CSS is also required.  Not sure exactly what to include.

Comment: mm..where did you added it?